# Why do some people see Sankhya as the highest truth?

Tags: advaita, sankhya

Some people believe Sankhya to be the highest truth. They neglect Advaita. What are their main points for believing like this? Isn't it generally understood and accepted that Advaita is the highest truth?

Comment: Question looks like opinion based.

Comment: No, advaita is not the only philosophy and highest truth. There are many other philosophies in Hinduism and many other philosophies in the world.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, IMO it's not asking SE users' opinion. OP is asking brlievers' opinion about why someone should at all think 1 philosophy to be higher than the other. We have several Qns like that. I read it as "What makes people choosing X over Y?". Valid.

Comment: @iammilind " Isn't it generally understood and accepted that Advaita is the highest truth?" This question is opinion based.  Reasons for believing Samkhya to be highest is also opinion based. Different people have different opinions. Some users may say Advaita is highest not Samkhya. Answers lead to debates.

Comment: It is not necessarily opinion-based. Scholarly arguments validating /establishing the superiority of sankhya may be provided as answers. It is an analysis not an opinion.